# Sticky header with hide and show on scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a navbar with two part (navbarTop and navbarBottom); navbarTop will shown when the scrollY is bigger than 110 and the navbarbottom will shown when the user scroll up, but my problem is that each component will be re-called after each scroll, even scrolling down, or when the navbottom already exist and the user scroll up and it's still keep calling the component.
here is the code:

```
const Navbar: FC = () => {

const [stickyHeader, setStickyHeader] = useState(false);
const [stickyMenu, setStickyMenu] = useState(false);

console.log('navbar')

const [y, setY] = useState(null);
const handleNavigation = useCallback(
    (e) => {
        const window = e.currentTarget;
        if (!stickyMenu) {
            if (y > window.scrollY) {
                setStickyMenu(true)
                // console.log("scrolling up");
            }
        }
        if (!stickyHeader) {
            if (window.scrollY >= 110) {
                setStickyHeader(true);
            }
        }
        if (stickyHeader) {
            if (window.scrollY <= 110) {
                setStickyHeader(false);
            }
        }
        if (stickyMenu) {
            if (y < window.scrollY) {
                setStickyMenu(false)
                // console.log("scrolling down");
            }
        }

        setY(window.scrollY);
    },
    [y, stickyMenu,stickyHeader]
);


useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleNavigation);

    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleNavigation);
    };
}, [handleNavigation, stickyMenu]);



return (
    <>
        <div className={s.root}>

            {stickyHeader === false ? (
                <div className='hidden xl:block md:w-auto'>
                    <NavbarTop sticky={false}/>
                    <NavbarBottom
                        sticky={false}/>
                </div>
            ) : (
                <div className='absolute hidden xl:block md:w-auto'>
                    <NavbarTop sticky={true}/>
                    {stickyMenu &&
                        <NavbarBottom sticky={true}/>
                    }
                </div>
            )}

            <SmallNav/>
        </div>
    </>

)
```

}
export default Navbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, I did not quite understand your question. You said that each component is re-called after each scroll. Of course it will be re-called, right?

Whenever you scroll, you change the `stickyHeader` or `stickyMenu`. React listens for the state change and re-renders the component. This is how React works.

I see that you're using tailwindcss.

You can use a `useMemo` to listen to the state and then return the appropriate class based on the different state states. This way you avoid having to create DOM nodes over and over again. I don't know if this would help you or not. I hope this will help you.

```js
const Navbar: FC = () => {
    const [stickyHeader, setStickyHeader] = useState(false);
    const [stickyMenu, setStickyMenu] = useState(false);
    // console.log('navbar');

    const [y, setY] = useState(null);
    const handleNavigation = useCallback(
        (e) => {
            const window = e.currentTarget;
            if (!stickyMenu) {
                if (y > window.scrollY) {
                    setStickyMenu(true);
                    // console.log("scrolling up");
                }
            }
            if (!stickyHeader) {
                if (window.scrollY >= 110) {
                    setStickyHeader(true);
                }
            }
            if (stickyHeader) {
                if (window.scrollY <= 110) {
                    setStickyHeader(false);
                }
            }
            if (stickyMenu) {
                if (y < window.scrollY) {
                    setStickyMenu(false);
                    // console.log("scrolling down");
                }
            }

            setY(window.scrollY);
        },
        [y, stickyMenu, stickyHeader],
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', handleNavigation);

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleNavigation);
        };
    }, [handleNavigation, stickyMenu]);

    const stickyClassName = useMemo(() => {
        if (stickyHeader) {
            return 'sticky top-0 xl:block md:w-auto';
        }
        return 'xl:block md:w-auto';
    }, [stickyHeader]);

    return (
        <div className="test" style={{ height: 2000 }}>
            <div className={stickyClassName}>
                <NavbarTop sticky={stickyHeader} />
                {stickyMenu && <NavbarBottom sticky={stickyHeader} />}
            </div>
            <div>SmallNav</div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: yeah you were right, I thought it shouldn't recall, but the scroll event will recall them and it's fine. also I thought using of useMemo, and it's actually worked (not totally) but in some recalls. thanks for answering juliomalves